# Cómo "limpiar" un iframe de la ventana padre usando JQuery

Tags: jquery, iframe

Tengo una página index.php donde defino varios iframe, entre ellos uno que es un menu.
Lo que quiero ahora es que desde menu.html, usando jquery, pueda "limpiar" un par de iframes de la ventana index, pero no me ha funcionado.

Mi código en index.php es:

```
      <table >
        <tr><td>
      <iframe src="menu.html" height="200" width="750" style="border:none;" name="iframe_menu"></iframe>
    </td>
    </tr>
      <tr><td>
      <iframe src="" height="500" width="750" style="border:none;" name="iframe_Unit" id="iframe_Unit" SCROLLING="no"></iframe>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </td> 
    <td>
      <table >
        <tr><td>
       <iframe src="./login.php" height="400" width="570" style="border:none;" name="iframe_ppal" id="iframe_ppal"></iframe>
    </td>
    </tr>
      <tr><td>
    <iframe src="" height="300" width="570" style="border:none;" name="iframe_activ" id="iframe_activ"></iframe>
     </td>
    </tr>
    </table> </td>  
  </tr>
</table>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

y mi código en menu.html es:

```
<script language="javascript" src="js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function (){
    $('#gohome').click( function() {
         window.top.$("#iframe_Unit").attr('src', 'about:blank');
      });
    })
</script>

<nav id="menu">
 
 <ul id="menu-horizontal">
  <li><a href="./Home.php" target="iframe_ppal" id="gohome" >Home</a></li>
```

He probado con parent, con top, usando .attr('src', 'about:blank'), .attr('src', ''), también probé .prop('src', '').

Comment: Hola maria, si utilizas solamente `$("iframe#iframe_Unit").attr('src', '');` te sigue sin funcionar?

Comment: probé como dices y tampoco me sirve, pero es que tampoco entiendo cómo podría pues en esa instrucción no veo cómo se referencia al padre, ya que estoy llamando desde un iframe hermano, por así decirlo

Comment: el `#gohome` es un boton? o donde se encuentra ubicado?

Comment: disculpa la demora en responder, el 8 operaron a mi hijo y he estado distraída. El ·gohome es un link href, y está ubicado en el iframe menu

Answer (score 2):

¡Lo logré!, se me ocurrió que podría crear una función javascrit en el padre (index.php), y llamarla desde el iframe hijo, y funcionó.

Aparte modifiqué la forma de limpiar el iframe, puse:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById("iframe_Unit");
      var html = "";

      iframe.contentWindow.document.open();
      iframe.contentWindow.document.write(html);
      iframe.contentWindow.document.close();
```